# Removing C from '55C' string and converting to float in a data file

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am trying to parse some data and I need the temperature number in the string.  I've narrowed it down to 55C with np.loadtxt but I don't know what to do to get rid of the C.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
s='File Comment Source_55C_1p2E-6mbar'
temp=np.loadtxt(s,delimiter='_',usecols=1)
```

Edit:

Sorry, I wasn't clear on what I was doing

```
VUV-Mini Spectrometer                       
Date    2021-07-02                  
Time    12:29:31.657                    
File Comment    Source_55C_1p2E-6mbar                   
Integration (ms)    2000                    
Averages    5                   
Slit    25 microns
```

This is the from the actual file I am parsing, I was using numpy.loadtxt to get to the comment I need, but numpy.loadtext is returning an error saying that I cannot convert string '55C' to float

```
temp=np.loadtxt(data01,delimiter='_',skiprows=3,usecols=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```py
In [1]: s = '55C'

In [2]: s.replace('C', '')
Out[2]: '55'
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract it precisely from the code you have provided, in a numerical data type:

```
import re

s='File Comment Source_55C_1p2E-6mbar'

# new code that solves your problem
mo = re.search('_([0-9]+)C_', s)
if mo:
    temp = float(mo.group(1))
print(temp)

temp=np.loadtxt(s,delimiter='_',usecols=1)
```